# Certificate from key store contains private key – even if the user does not have access rights

Tags: c#, powershell, .net-core, certificate, x509certificate

I was doing some testing when I came across this very strange behavior…which I do not fully understand.

First I created a self-signed certificate using Powershell:

```
# Creates a certificate and adds it to the certificate store (private key included)
$certInfo = New-SelfSignedCertificate -NotBefore (Get-Date) -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(300) -Subject "MyTestCert" -DnsName "localhost" -KeyAlgorithm "RSA" -KeyLength 2048 -HashAlgorithm "SHA256" -CertStoreLocation "Cert:\LocalMachine\My" -FriendlyName "MyTestCert" 

Write-Host "Created cert: $($certInfo.Subject) - $($certInfo.Thumbprint)"

# Exports the certificate as pfx (private key included)
$PFXPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "123456" -Force -AsPlainText
Export-PfxCertificate -Cert "cert:\LocalMachine\My\$($certInfo.Thumbprint)" -Password $PFXPass -FilePath "C:\Temp\$($certInfo.Subject.SubString(3)).pfx"
```

This successfully creates a certificate with the subject “MyTestCert” and the certificate has a private key.

[image: Windows key store]

Looking at the permissions (All Tasks > Manage Private Keys… ) you can see that the key is available for administrators but not for “normal” users.

[image: Manage private keys]

Next I executed my C# code (.NET core 2.2) (VS debugging, running without admin priviliges ) which reads the certificate from the store and tries to use the certificates private key:

```
internal class Program
{
   private static X509Certificate2 GetCertFromFile()
   {
       const String certFileName = @"C:\Temp\MyTestCert.pfx";
       var cert = new X509Certificate2( certFileName, "123456", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet );
       return cert;
   }

   private static X509Certificate2 GetCertFromStore()
   {
       using ( var store = new X509Store( StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine ) )
       {
           store.Open( OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly );

           var matchingCerts = store.Certificates.Find( X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "MyTestCert", false );
           return matchingCerts[0];
       }
   }

   private static void Main( String[] args )
   {
       var certificate = GetCertFromStore();

       // Does throw exception "Keyset does not exist"
       try
       {
           var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
       }
       catch ( CryptographicException ex )
       {
           Console.WriteLine( ex );
       }

       certificate = GetCertFromFile();
       // This will work
       var rsa1 = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();

       Console.ReadLine();
   }
}
```

As expected, the certificate loaded from the store (`GetCertFromFile`) does not contain a private key.
(The certificate contains a private key when executed as administrator.)
The certificate loaded from the PFX file (`GetCertFromFile`) does contain a private key.

**Now comes the strange part.**

When I execute the application for a second time, the certificate loaded from the store (`GetCertFromFile`) DOES contain a private key.

Why does the key store allow me access to the private key of the certificate AFTER I’ve read the PFX file?

Comment: Why is that strange? The certificate store and the file system does not correlate. Meaning if you delete one the other would still exist. Further more Certificate store items are different objects than a file system objects, and so are the access rights on those and how they work. What is the purpose of the exported certificate? If the certificate is ment for server installation, then yes. Then the certificate must hold the private key. If the exported certificate is ment for client installation then you must ensure that you export the certificate without private key.

Comment: @ThomasK I am aware of that. Key store and file are two different and independent things. Strange is, that I can get the private key from the KEY STOR after the application has at least once accessed the private key stored in the FILE. I would expect the key store to always deny access to the private key (which apparently is not the case). .... Just to be clear. I’m doing some local testing I would never make a private key available to a client (at least not intentionally). The application should be (and is) able to read the private key from the file.

Comment: Ok. This is an educated guess. The private keys are stored via Microsoft's Cryptography API. consult [link](https://superuser.com/questions/1061638/where-are-certificate-private-keys-stored-in-windows-7) Since the signature of the two certificates are equal the API can fetch the corresponding private key from the Store. I would guess if you only load from file, you could still get the private key.

Comment: I had a similar strange error where, I think, I could load a certificate from the cert store and attach it to a request but, if the user did not have permission to access the cert, the request would fail validation. 

In some sense, I think the permissions on certificates refers to their use but not some levels of "access".